# Sort Dojo store items

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

So, I have a dojo script wherein I'm pushing 4 rows into a data grid. Something like this,

```
var data = {
            identifier: "id",
            items: []
            };

var data_list = [
        { col1: "normal", col2: false, col3: 'Cut are not followed by two hexadecimal', col4: 29.91},
        { col1: "important", col2: false, col3: 'Decause a % sign always indicates', col4: 9.33},
        { col1: "important", col2: false, col3: 'Aigns can be selectively', col4: 19.34},
        { col1: "normal", col2: false, col3: 'Begin the action', col4: 5.6}
        ];

var rows = 4;

for(var i = 0, l = data_list.length; i < rows; i++)
{
    data.items.push(lang.mixin({ id: i+1 }, data_list[i%l]));
}

var store = new ItemFileWriteStore({data: data});

/*set up layout*/
var layout = [[
        {name: 'Column 1', field: 'id', width: '100px'},
        {name: 'Column 2', field: 'col2', width: '100px'},
        {name: 'Column 3', field: 'col3', width: '200px'},
        {name: 'Column 4', field: 'col4', width: '150px'}
        ]];

/*create a new grid*/
var grid = new DataGrid({
            id: 'grid',
            store: store,
            structure: layout,
            rowSelector: '20px'});
```

Then, I have a functionality where I use

```
dojo.forEach(grid.store._arrayOfAllItems, function (item) {
//do something
}
```

But before the forEach loop is called, I need to sort the items with respect to **col3**

Now, to sort the items based on **col3**, I've tried

```
            var noOfItems = store._arrayOfAllItems.length;
            var items = new Array(noOfItems);
            for(i = 0; i < noOfItems; i++)
            {
                items[i] = grid.getItem(i);
            }

            for(i = 0; i < noOfItems; i++)
            {
                for(j = 0; j < noOfItems - 1; j++)
                {
                    var a = store.getValue(items[j], "col3");
                    var b = store.getValue(items[j+1], "col3");

                    if(a.localeCompare(b) == 1)
                    {
                        [items[j], items[j+1]] = [items[j+1], items[j]];
                    }
                }
            }

            grid.setItems(items);
```

But, even then,

```
 for(i = 0; i < grid.store._arrayOfAllItems.length; i++)
 {
    var items = grid.store._arrayOfAllItems;
    document.write(grid.store.getValue(items[i], "col3")+"<br>");
 }
```

Prints the unsorted arrangement of items.
I've also tried using

```
grid.store.fetch({onComplete: displaySortItems , sort: [{attribute: "col3"}] });
```

But turns out fetch() does not return anything [fetch() FAQ](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/quickstart/data/usingdatastores/faq.html) and even when I tried sorting the items in the **displaySortItems()** it's not being reflected beyond the scope of the function.

So, is there any way I can get a sorted array(based on **col3**) of items when `grid.store._arrayOfAllItems` is used.

*or*

Can I sort the items array and make the changes to hold even when `grid.store._arrayOfAllItems` is used. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to write callback functions to use fetch(). The documentation for ItemFileReadStore provides an [example for custom sorting](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore.html#demonstrating-custom-sorting).
At a minimum you need a function for onComplete and onError.

```
var gotItems = function(items, request) {
    // Process your items here
    for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    console.log(items[i]);
    }
};

var fetchFailed = function(error, request) {
    alert("Fetch failed");
};

var sortAttributes = [{attribute: "col3", descending: false}];

store.fetch({query: {}, onComplete: gotItems, onError: fetchFailed, sort: sortAttributes});
```

**UPDATE**: `fetch()` sorts while it delivers the items and not internally. If you want to sort again you can call `fetch()` again, providing another function for `onComplete`.

In dojo properties that start with '_', (like _arrayOfAllItems) are considered 'private'. You can still access them but it is not a good idea to modify them. ItemFileWriteStore will manage it internally. If you want a sorted array you can built your own copy in a function you pass to `fetch()`.

Comment: As I have mentioned, the `fetch()` and `onComplete` along with `sort: sortAttributes` sorts the items[] just fine. But my problem is that the sorted items[] array does not remain sorted after `store.fetch()` call. Try printing all the item values as `grid.store.getValue(items[i], "col3")` after the `store.fetch();`. They are unsorted again!

Comment: `fetch()` stores while it delivers the items and not internally. If you want to sort again you can call `fetch()` again providing another function for `onComplete`.

Comment: So, is there no other way I will be able to sort the items[] such that `grid.store._arrayOfAllItems` returns a sorted array ? :(

Comment: I updated the answer. If you want a sorted array the best option is to create a separate copy.

Comment: I have already tried what you said. Copied the `items[]` into `newItems[]`. Sorted the `newItems[]` and then `grid.setItems(newItems);`. But in vain. The grid still prints out the unsorted items[] data. Please please help!

Comment: Grids have their own sorting. In DataGrid you can set the sortInfo property. Or you can call `grid.setSortIndex(3,true); grid.sort();` to sort the third colcumn.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the sort order when you initialize the grid.

```
var grid = new Grid({
    sortInitialOrder: [{colId: "Genre", descending: true},{colId: "Artist", descending: true}]
});
```

Comment: But I don't want to sort the grid initially, I only want the sorted grid(w.r.t **col3**) before calling 
`dojo.forEach(grid.store._arrayOfAllItems, function (item) {}`

Comment: Try using a function for sorting arrays of object.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I have already done that. But the grid does not stay sorted after the scope of the function.